# Android: How to stop instrumentation test after first failure

Tags: android, testing, android-instrumentation

We have a suite of Android instrumentation tests which we run from CL via `./gradlew app:connectedDebugAndroidTest` If there is a failing test we basically have to wait for all of them to complete before the HTML report is generated. What we would like is for the testing to stop on the first failing test. Is there a gradle flag we can apply to make this happen? I haven't found anything in the official docs.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better (and in effect faster) to have the result of all tests? So you know immediately that test 1, 3 and 5 fail, instead of fixing issue of test 1, then learn that test 3 also fails, fixing that, then learn that test 5 also fails ...

Comment: No cause we usually only have one failing test. If we do have more than one it's likely for the same root reason.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you found a solution yet, but I was thinking about it and I came up with using a `TestRunner` or `TestRule`. I think the `TestRunner` approach is more appropriate though. I'm not the biggest fan of the companion objects / static fields used, but it works. I've tested it using a single emulator, but not with sharded tests across multiple emulators (but I think it won't propagate the any failure across all emulators).

### Custom test runner

A custom `TestRunner` that is aware of test failures and ignores tests after the first test fails. I've created a cut down version of `AndroidJUnit4` with the functionality here: https://gist.github.com/AniFichadia/0a0aa665dfc554e963d2ab3276247efb#file-skiponfirstfailuretestrunner-kt

`AndroidJUnit4` essentially delegates to either `androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner` or `org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner`.

The above implementation has a subclass of `AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner` and prevents test methods from running (by treating them as ignored) if any test fails. If you need `Robolectric`, then the implementation for a custom `RobolectricTestRunner` is the same as the custom `AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner` in the gist, and you can use a similar check as what's in `AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(Class)`.

To use it, you just have to annotate your test classes with the runner: `@RunWith(SkipOnFirstFailureTestRunner::class)`.

Just have to watch out if `AndroidJUnit4` changes internally (eg. with Nitrogen).

### Custom test rule

A test rule that will skip tests after the first test fails (by treating them as ignored):
https://gist.github.com/AniFichadia/0a0aa665dfc554e963d2ab3276247efb#file-skiponfirstfailuretestrule-kt

You need to add the rule to your test classes and this can be applied to unit test classes too. It logs the first failed test, but I don't like this approach though.

### Enabling the `TestRunner` / `TestRule`

Perhaps you could use a `BuildConfig` field to enable it. This can be set to true in a non-productionised variant if the tests are running on CICD.

For the `TestRunner` you need to set the `enabled` property in the class itself.

For the `TestRule`, you can set if it's enabled using the `enabled` field in the constructor wherever it's being used.

Let me know what you think.